# Matlab Solution Needed

Tags: matlab

```
function [est k ] = approximate_e( delta )
%APPROXIMATE_E Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
n =1;
est = 0;
while abs(exp(1)-est)>delta 
    if n ==1
        est = 1;
    end
    if n == 2
        est = 2;
    end
    if n >2
        est = est+1/prod(1:(n-1));
    end
    fprintf "e is %d and n is %d:  \n",est,n
    k = n;
    n = n + 1;
    if n >10000
        fprinf "n is greater than 10000.\n"
        break;
    end
end
```

I wrote the preceding code in an attempt to answer a question involving the computation of Eulers Number.  The question follows:

> Write a function called approximate_e that uses the following formula
>   to compute e, Euler’s number:

[image]

Instead of going to infinity, the function stops at the smallest k for which the approximation differs from exp(1) (i.e., the

> value returned MATLAB’s built-in function) by no more than the
>   positive scalar, delta, which is the only input argument. The first
>   output of the function is the approximate value of e, while the second
>   is k. (Note: if your program or the grader takes a long time, you may
>   have created an infinite loop and need to hit Ctrl-C on your
>   keyboard.) You are not allowed to use the built-in function factorial.

Comment: And where is the question ?

Comment: So what is your code doing that is unexpected (other than the `fprintf`s)?

Answer (score 0):

```
function [est] = approximate_e( delta )
%APPROXIMATE_E Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
n = 0;
est = 0;
TerminationCondition = 10000;
while abs(exp(1)-est)>delta 
    est = 1/factorial(n)+est;
    display(['The current value of est is ', num2str(est),char(10)]);
    n = n + 1;
    if n > TerminationCondition
        break;
    end
end
if n > TerminationCondition
    display(['n is greater than ', num2str(TerminationCondition), ' terminating loop']);
else
    display(['This estimation took ', num2str(n), ' cycles to complete']);
end
```

You'll have to adjust the function to give you the k value (which is the variable n).